# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list': how can i split a lista with a float?

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I'm putting together a code in which I take the percentage of the numbers from the npp_pls list and I want to divide the result obtained with the numbers from the mass_seed list but this error is appearing

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'float' and 'list'

my code is as follows:

```
npp_pls = [10, 80, 5]
mass_seed = [0.1, 1.0, 3.0] #atributo variante 

for npp_rep in npp_pls:  
    npp_rep = npp_rep *0.1 

    print(npp_rep)



new_results = (npp_rep) / (mass_seed)
print(new_results)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use zip to iterate over both lists at the same time and do your calculations like this:

```
npp_pls = [10, 80, 5]
mass_seed = [0.1, 1.0, 3.0] #atributo variante 

result = [npp_rep * 0.1 / ms for npp_rep, ms in zip(npp_pls, mass_seed)]
```

EDIT:
Your error occurs because you are trying to divide a float `npp_rep` by a list `mass_seed`. Instead you probably want to divide `npp_rep` by the corresponding value in mass_seed

Comment: This answer would be better with an explanation of why the OP is getting the errors that they are. +1, anyway, I somehow forgot `zip` existed.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I added some explanation. Feel free to change it :)

Answer (score 0):

`new_results = (npp_rep) / (mass_seed)` part on runtime will be like `new_results = 5 / [0.1, 1.0, 3.0]`, that is not supported.

So you can reach the result doing something like this:

```
new_results = [x / y for x, y in zip(npp_pls, mass_seed)]
```

Also i should mention that your `for loop` doesn't cause any changes and just do some multiply and doesn't save them anywhere, you can do this instead of your `for loop`:

```
npp_pls = [npp_rep * 0.1 for npp_rep in npp_pls]
```